# CSS: Divs on mobile still appear at the same width as desktop even though media queries were added

Tags: css, media-queries

This one's really odd. I have a hero area on this site (https://dev-acupuncture.pantheonsite.io/) and it's two columns (div's) that are 50% width on desktop and what should be 100% on mobile. However, when I check it on mobile, the div's are still at 50% width even though I have a media query set up to make it 100%. Like this:

```
.hero-left, .hero-right { height: 500px; width: 50%; margin: 0; }
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .hero-left, .hero-right { width: 100%; }
}
```

I checked Console and it sees the query, but it doesn't seem to want to respect it. So everything is still at 50%. Really puzzled why this is occurring. Here's my HTML for that area.

```
<section class="hero">
  <div class="hero-left" data-parallax="scroll" data-position-y="15px" data-image-src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/hero.jpg">
    <div class="hero-content">
        <p>Text goes here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hero-right">
    <div class="hero-right-top" data-parallax="scroll" data-position-y="15px" data-image-src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/hero2.jpg">
        <div class="hero-content">
            <p>Text goes here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hero-right-bottom" data-parallax="scroll" data-position-y="15px" data-image-src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/hero3.jpg">
        <div class="hero-content">
            <p>Text goes here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't reflect the code on the provided link. Provide the full stylesheet for the hero so people can help. Also, I would suggest you to try and learn to debug these things with browser devtools (e.g. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools). For your specific case, the problem is not the width, but the `display: flex;` on the `.hero` class.

Comment: specify the meta view-port tag within html <header>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your site, you need to define flex-wrap for the .hero class, as well as use vh instead of px when defining the height:

```
.hero {flex-wrap: wrap; height: 100vh;}
```

Comment: that does work, but now when I switch to mobile view, the content underneath crashes into the hero.

Comment: Never mind, made a media query and simply changed the height to auto. All good and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe if make a media queri for small devices to